# code error CString in MFC Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, mfc

If I add arr(1)=HelloWorld, It Works!

but If I add arr(1)=Hello,world or Hello_World or Hello World

It Doesn't!

A snippet of my code is enclosed below:

```
void CMFCApplicationFileDlg::OnClickBtnToData()
{

CString dataIn;
m_txtDataInput.GetWindowTextW(dataIn);  
int dem = 0;
int check = 0;
CString mangMaHoa[] = { _T("A"), _T("B"), _T("C"), _T("D"), _T("E"), _T("F"), _T("G"), _T("H"), _T("I"), _T("J"), _T("K"), _T("L"), _T("M"), _T("O"), _T("P"), _T("Q"), _T("R"), _T("S"), _T("T"), _T("U"), _T("V"), _T("W"), _T("X"), _T("Y"), _T("Z") };
int num = arr[1].GetLength();
CString mahoa, chuoiSauMaHoa;

for (int i = 0; i < arr[1].GetLength(); i++)
{
    mahoa = arr[1].Mid(i, 1);
    dem = 0;
    check = 0;
 
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        {
            if (mangMaHoa[j].CompareNoCase(mahoa) == 0)
            {
                check += 1;
                if (j >= 23)
                {
                    dem = j + 3;
                    dem = dem - 26;
                }
                else
                {
                    dem = j + 3;

                }
                chuoiSauMaHoa += mangMaHoa[dem];
                break;
            }
            else
            {

                continue;
            }
        }
        if (check == 0)
        {
            chuoiSauMaHoa += mahoa;
        }       
}
m_txtDataOutput.SetWindowTextW(chuoiSauMaHoa);

}

if (check == 0)
{
    chuoiSauMaHoa += mahoa;
}
```

I wish to get all characters

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot:]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is not explicit about what arr is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying a lot on the magic number 26 which you presume to be the length of your array mangMaHoa.

However it's actually of length 25 (did you intend leaving out letter N?)

So out-of-bounds errors are going to happen especially when searching for your special characters `,`, `_` and `space`.

Instead of presuming what you think to be the size of the array you should be defensive and determine the actual size of the array

```
size_t alphabet = sizeof(mangMaHoa) / sizeof(mangMaHoa[0]);
```

and use the result instead.

Comment: A safer version for your expression would be [_countof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773.aspx). It fails to compile should the argument be a pointer rather than an array.